# Relation of BRST model of equivariant cohomology and BRST cohomology?

Tags: cohomology, quantum-field-theory, lie-algebra-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

I'm now reading Kalkman's paper "[BRST model for equivariant cohomology and representation for equivariant Thom class](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104252784)". And I've seen his definition for BRST model is

> $B=W(\mathfrak{g})\otimes \Omega(M)$, $W(\mathfrak{g})=S^*(\mathfrak{g}^*)\otimes \bigwedge^*(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ is the Weil algebra. Let $\phi^a$ be generators of $S(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ and $\omega^a$ are generators of $\wedge^*(\mathfrak{g}^*)$, we have $$\begin{align*}\delta\phi^a&=-f_{bc}^a\omega^b\phi^c\\\delta \omega^a&=-\frac{1}{2}f_{bc}^a\omega^b\omega^c+\phi^a\\ \delta \eta&=d\eta+\omega^a\mathcal{L}_a\eta-\phi^b \imath_b\eta\end{align*}$$ Here $f_{bc}^a $ is structure constant for $\mathfrak{g}$, $\eta$ a differential form, $d$ the usual de Rham differential,$\mathcal{L}$ $\imath$ are lie derivative and retraction respectively.

From Anton Alekseev's lecture notes [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=V9_tCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&dq=equivariant%20cohomology%20anton&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE8N-k4qDMAhVosoMKHaDOAkIQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=equivariant%20cohomology%20anton&f=false) page 13 (also seen in physics), we have on Weil algebra

> $$\begin{align*}\delta\phi^a&=-f_{bc}^a\omega^b\phi^c\\\delta \omega^a&=-\frac{1}{2}f_{bc}^a\omega^b\omega^c\end{align*}$$

From Figueroa-O’Farrill's lecture note [here](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/BRST/Notes.pdf) page 32, his definition is similar but in different space, the space is not Weil algebra but Chevalley-Eilenberg complex. The definition is now

> On $\bigwedge^*\mathfrak{g}^*\otimes \bigwedge^*\mathfrak{g}\otimes C^\infty(M)$, $D=\{Q,-\}$, where $$Q=\alpha^l\phi_l-f_{jk}^l\alpha^j\wedge\alpha^k\wedge X_l,$$Here $X_l$ are basis for $\mathfrak{g}$ with $[X_i,X_j]=f_{ij}^k X_k$, $\alpha^l$ are basis for $\mathfrak{g}^*$.

Maybe it's just a dumb question, but I just couldn't understand why all these are called BRST opeartors. How could we go from the physics BRST operator to Kalkman's BRST operator? How could we go from $\bigwedge^*\mathfrak{g}$ to $S^*\mathfrak{g}$(To me there does not seem to be a canonical way and reason to do so).

Thanks!

Comment: Section 10 of "Lectures on 2D Yang-Mills Theory, Equivariant Cohomology and Topological Field Theories" arXiv: 9411210 may help to understand these different models

Comment: [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44224) states that the BRST procedure computes (a generalization of) the usual equivariant cohomology of a manifold with a group action.